# Jquery focus to first inputbox when user save details

Tags: jquery

i have four input field name,age,city,save details(input type="button")
when user fill data in first textbox and press enter, cursor moves to next textbox, and finally when cursor in save button that time when user press enter all details saved and cursor focus to age textbox. but what need is cursor move to name textbox. kindly solve my issue
below is the code i'm using in jquery

```
//cursor move code
            var currentBoxNumber = 0;
            $(".cursormove").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            textboxes = $("input.cursormove");
            currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
            console.log(textboxes.index(this));
            if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
            }
}
    });
            //all entered data send to insert.php when user click save button and reset all fields and focus again to first input
            $("#save").click(function () { 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
                    //dataType: "dataType",
                    success: function (response) {
                      $("<tr></tr>").html(response).appendTo(".table");
                      $("#frm")[0].reset();
                      $("#name").focus();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="frm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control cursormove" placeholder="Enter name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="age">Age</label>
                      <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control cursormove" placeholder="Enter age">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="city">City</label>
                      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control cursormove" placeholder="Enter city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="0">
                      <input type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-success cursormove" value="Save Details" >
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue

```
var currentBoxNumber = 0;
$(".cursormove").keydown(function (event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
textboxes = $("input.cursormove");
currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);
console.log(textboxes.index(this));
if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
nextBox.focus();
nextBox.select();
event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. But only if the Id s and Class names in your jQuery matches correctly.
Make sure your Name input has the correct id `<input id="name"` and age input has another id.
Add HTML code to investigate more.